# Set image to switch in swift

Tags: swift

how can i set image to UIswitch on the white round part [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to modify the `UISwitch`. Instead create your custom control that you will be able to fully customize. Subclass the `UIControl` and implement your own user interface. As a reference [this repo](https://github.com/dimitris-c/ToggleSwitch) may help you.

Comment: thnx for help i am sure it will work